# How to convert CSV file to Esri shapefile using asp.net c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gis, arcgis, shapefile

How can I convert a **CSV** file to **ESRI shapefile** In asp.net or c#?

Is it possible to convert non-spatial data to spatial data?

I.e. the latitude and longitude of a point.

I have tried using **Geodatabase conversion techniques** which is available in the internet but nothing works in asp.

Comment: you need to use any of the GIS library from any of the library provider like Thinkgeo or any other

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how can i convert a csv file to feature class in arc gis using asp.net c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44132353/how-can-i-convert-a-csv-file-to-feature-class-in-arc-gis-using-asp-net-c-sharp)

Comment: @SirRufo It's not duplicate of that post. FeatureClass and Shapefile are ttwo different things.

Comment: @SirRufo featured class and shape file are not the same

Comment: No, you cannot convert non-spatial data to spatial data. Where would the spatial component come from? If you have geographical coordinates in your csv-file on the other hand, it's already spatial and you need to convert from one spatial format to another. Hint: Google how to read a csv-file and google how to write a shapefile. Your question will probably be closed as being to broad.

Comment: Then this question is about how to read csv file, geodata conversion and writing esri shapefile and the last question is about reading csv file, geodata conversion and create FeatureClass? Seems both are too broad